# Mutually independence of all combinations of 3 out of 4 random variables implies the mutual independence of 4 RVs?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

Suppose we have four random variables: A,B,C,D. Any three of the four RVs are mutually independent. In other words, (A,B,C) are mutually independent, (A,B,D) are mutually independent, (A,C,D) are mutually independent, (B,C,D) are mutually independent. Does this imply (A,B,C,D) are mutually independent? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Counterexample.** Consider four independent tosses of a fair coin.
$X_1=1$ if the first and second tosses come up the same, $X_1=0$ otherwise.
$X_2=1$ if the second and third tosses come up the same, $X_2=0$ otherwise.
$X_3=1$ if the third and fourth tosses come up the same, $X_3=0$ otherwise.
$X_4=1$ if the fourth and first tosses come up the same, $X_4=0$ otherwise.
Any three of these variables are mutually independent, but all four are not.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $X_1, \dots, X_n$ independent Bernoulli random variables all with $p=\frac12$. Then let $X_{n+1}$ be the XOR of all of them (i.e. add them all up then reduce mod $2$). Then we have a set of $n+1$ random variables that are not independent. But any subset of $n$ of them is independent.

Answer (score 1):

No. For random variables $X_1,...,X_n$ to be independent, any $n \choose j$ selection of them must be independent, $j = 2,...,n$. So in your example, we must have $A, B, C, D$ independent.